# How to force email address validation when creating an account in Azure AD B2C using the Graph API?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am able to create a user on Azure AD B2C using the Graph API by doing a `POST` on:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "some.email@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "My Display Name",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "P@ssword!",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

I found it odd that there was no email sent to the passed in email address to confirm that the email address is a real one. Are there some other parameters I should set so Azure AD B2C sends out an email with a kind of verification code or link to activate the account only then?

Comment: Have you managed to achieve this with Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that email validation is not done in AAD Graph API is that a `Tenant Admin` is calling this api to create account. so onus of ensuring that email address is valid falls on the `Tenant Admin`.

I assume your scenario is that you want to `invite` users but enable account only if the email address is valid. You can create the account in a disabled node, using `accountEnabled` property. When user signs in, you can enable the user by setting this flag to true.

You will need to use Custom Policies for this scenario.

You can also use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) if you have an invite scenario

Comment: I am not really doing an invitation. I have a mobile app that uses my Spring Boot backend to create a user account using the Graph API. But the result is the same. I create the account with `accountEnabled` set to `false` and later do a PATCH on the endpoint of the user with `accountEnabled` set tot `true`.